# Is there a way to group players by color-coding their names?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to set up a local Minecraft server (e.g. 'local' as in 'my hometown') for parents and kids I know.

I would like to be able to put the parents in one group and kids in another by color-coding their names.  (e.g. parents names in 'yellow', kids names in 'red').

Is there a way to do this at all?

Comment: Hi, Ray; I've modified your question to not require plugins in order to answer the question.  If there is one, someone can answer with it, but it shouldn't preclude the possibility that it might be possible without one.

Comment: Works for me. Ty!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a way to do this in Vanilla Minecraft, using the [Scoreboard feature](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard). You don't even need to create an actual score to track. Just use commands along the lines of

```
/scoreboard teams add greenteam
/scoreboard teams add redteam
/scoreboard teams add blueteam
/scoreboard teams option greenteam color green
/scoreboard teams option redteam color red
/scoreboard teams option blueteam color blue
```

This example creates three rather unimaginatively-named teams, and gives each team its own color. Feel free to choose the names of the teams however you want. Then use

```
/scoreboard teams join <team> <player>
```

to put a given person on a given team. This will make their name take on the team's color in chat, above their head, and on the Tab menu of all currently-signed-in players.

While the team mechanics can be used to do things like team-based disabling of friendly fire and the like, the default settings are for a player's team to have no direct, actual effects on gameplay.

Comment: If user logoff/logon, are they on the same team?  If i start/stop server, are teams remembered?

Comment: The server remembers all team information. As long as your world is intact, teams should remain the same.

Comment: In 1.13, the teams feature was split to its own command: `/team foo` instead of `/scoreboard teams foo`